# What is the difference between yarn build and yarn install?

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

What exactly these two do, where to use them ?

- `yarn install`
- `yarn build`

Comment: yarn install will install all dependancies listed in `package.json`. build will perform an operation which you have mentioned inside scripts key `build` inside `package.json`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a nutshell, `yarn install` is the command used to install all dependencies for a project, usually allocated in the **package.json** file. In most scenarios it is because you cloned a project and need its dependencies installed to run it.

On the other hand, `yarn build` is not a built-in command in the [Yarn package manager](https://yarnpkg.com/en/). Looking at your question, it seems like you are running some #reactjs project, which might have defined a `build` command in its **package.json** file.

I hope this clarifies your doubt, but for a complete answer, please provide an example of what is your specific scenario.

Also be aware that when running custom scripts like build, test, deploy, etc. it is recommended tu use the `yarn run [script]` command as stated in the [Yarn docs](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/run/), in your case `yarn run build`.

Comment: oh i see now. I didnt now know it's a custom configured command. Ty

Comment: No problem, you can check out the complete list of available cli commands from Yarn [here](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/), any script that is not there is custom.

Answer (score 3):

`yarn install` is used to fetch and install all dependencies for your project which are defined in your **package.json**. You might want to do this when you add a dependency or if you freshly checked out the project on another computer. Also read [the docs](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/install/) on yarn install.

`yarn run build` calls the script that you configured for the "build" command in your **package.json**. Note that *yarn build* is not a valid yarn command.

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d lib" // <-- this will be executed
  }
}
```

Also see the [yarn run documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/run/)